# Table-row width 100% not respecting parent

Tags: html, css

I have a codepen example: http://codepen.io/19wolf/pen/myrOew?editors=110

You'll notice that the dropdown on "Item One" stretches across the entire page. How do I force it to fit under "Item One" and only "Item One" (there being a variable number of items)? I've tried changing `li:hover ul` from `display: table` to `display: table-row` but all that does is make the items shorter than "Item One".

I had definitely gotten this to work in the past using the current html setup, but that css got lost...

The semi-live site I'm running it on is [apoxz.org/new](http://apoxz.org/new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give position relative to your li which hold another level of ul:

```
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    position : relative;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Except it doesn't seem to work on Firefox... :/

Comment: let me check for fireforx.

Comment: it is same. no issue, except vertical scroll coming when hover li. it will come when your height grow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the **li** width on **hover**:

```css
nav {
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 display: table;
}

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

nav li {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0 .5em;

}

nav a {
 background: #0033ab;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 1em;
 text-align: center;
}
nav a:hover {
 background: #f7b512;
 color: #000;
}

nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   position: absolute;
 width:30%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
 display: table-row;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Item One</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>SubOne</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>SubTwo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>SubThree</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Item Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work with a variable number of items?